# How to traverse the two yuan dictionary in the Django template

Tags: django, templates

**1.my view have a dict,For example：**

```
category_all = {
    u'Python': {
        'acticle_info': [
            [<Article: python_tump>],[<Article:python_dict>]
         ],
         'article_count': 22
     }
}
```

**2.my render is:**

```
return render(request, 'blog/index.html',{'category_all':category_all})
```

**3.i traverse the dict in Django template:**

```
  <!-- tabs Nav  -->
  <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    {% for blog_category in category_all.keys %}
       <li role="presentation"><a href="#{{ blog_category }}" aria-controls="{{ blog_category }}" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">{{ blog_category }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
    {% for blog_category,blog_info in category_all.items %}
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="{{ blog_category }}">
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <tbody>
                {% for get_blog_info in blog_info.acticle_info %}
                    {% for blog_result  in get_blog_info %}
                        <tr class="active">
                            <td><a href="{% url 'blog_detail' num=blog_result.pk %}">{{ blog_result.title }}</a></td>
                            <td>{{ blog_result.date_publish }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor get_blog_info %}
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    % endfor %}
</div>
```

**4.help**
4.1.How to get the article_count value

4.2.I used a lot of for loop, how can reduce the for cycle

Answer (score 0):

You can get `article_count` value by:

```
 blog_info.article_count
```

Change your `category_all` structure for reduce loops!